# Converting bytecode back to char in c# win. form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a piece of code which **returns byte code of any character** which is shown below

```
string ByteCodeValue = Convert.ToString((char)65533, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
//which returns value "1111111111111101"
```

but when i try to do it vice-versa it does not work and gives an exception as follows "**Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.**"

```
char OldChar= (char)Convert.ToByte("1111111111111101", 2);
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not a bytecode of a character, that is binary of that character :-)

Comment: 65533 exceeds byte.maxvalue (255) by quite a lot. Use a char

Comment: Well a byte has up to 8 digits (of 1 or 0) in it so the value "1111111111111101" is not a byte representation of a char.

Comment: 65533 is in range of short not byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting 16-bit unsigned value, not byte (8 bit). See [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x9h8tsay.aspx). Try using:

```
 var oldChar = (char)Convert.ToUInt16(ByteCodeValue,2);
```

Comment: thank you sir it was just the thing i was looking for